# Uploading image files to server using PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am having trouble saving the image from the upload script that I have created. I used a tutorial from w3schools and even created the uploads directory with the permissions 755. I get the error "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file"

This is the upload form

````
Select image to upload:<br><br><br>
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>


//This is the script that is called after the picture is submitted:

<?php
    $target_dir = 'https://yoda.kean.edu/~ankrahph/CPS4921/uploads';
    $target_file = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
       && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        }
    }
    ?>```
````

Comment: You have set up an web url as `$target_dir`. You probably will need to change that to a local directory.